# ng-repeat for a 3+ levels deep hierarchy

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, nested-loops

I wonder if there's a sane way of `ng-repeat`-ing in a multilevel structure. Imagine data like this

- top

  - middle
  - 1
  - 2
  - middle
  - 3
  - 4
  - 5
- top

  - middle
  - 6
  - middle
  - 7
  - 8
  - 9

Displaying then as an HTML list means `N` nested loop (this is simple for a fixed `N`). The same for a table doesn't work as all the `<tr>`s must be on the same level. There's a [trick employing `tbody`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18097648/581205), but it saves a single level only.

For 2 levels, it's simple with `ng-repeat-start/end`. For 3 levels, I need an invisible row like in this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/lVJ3tm5IKSykNo48CF9A?p=preview). I wonder if there's a clean solution and how it can be extended to 4 levels (I really do hope I don't need 5).

Comment: Since you didn't state anything of sorts, is there any reason that you can't transform the data into the flat list you seem to wan't for the table purely for display purposes?...

Comment: @Jens Sure, I can transform it, and I guess, it's the best solution. The table should be editable (all rows 2-way bound), but this can be done with the flat list, too.

Comment: It's not that I think it can't be done, got somewhat close by tweaking https://github.com/dotJEM/angular-tree a bit, but not close enough, and in the end I think you will end up with something that is fairly complex, therefore prone to more errors... So I think that transforming it would be the desired solution as it would be less complex, therefore more likely to end up right.

Comment: @Jens: I guess you're right... although the solution is pretty trivial (see my own answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is actually pretty simple, just start with

```
 <tr ng-repeat-start="x1 in list">
```

repeat

```
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="x_n_plus_one in x_n">
```

so many times as needed and finish with a

```
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-if=0>
```

It really doesn't feel like nested loop, but [it works](http://plnkr.co/edit/lVJ3tm5IKSykNo48CF9A?p=preview).

---

That said, I guess I'd rather flatten my list instead as it makes handling of empty lists more flexible and clear.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to modify the data itself to be more structured, then it becomes trivial.  For example a 4 level data structure.

```
var data = [ 
  { name: 'level 1', values: [
      { name: 'level 2', values: [
          { name: 'level 3', values: [
            { name: 'level 4', values: [] }
          ]}
      ]}
  ]} 
]
```

And here is the markup for the ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="level1 in data">
   <div ng-repeat="level2 in level1.values">
       <div ng-repeat="level3 in level2.values">
          <div ng-repeat="level4 in level3.values"></div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, you're solving a problem I don't have. You're nesting `div`s, but my problem are the `tr`, as they mustn't be nested.

Comment: You can get the same look and feel of a table using divs with some css magic, is there a reason you must use a table?

Comment: I really want to avoid the CSS magic. With a table, I can easily add a column or whatever, the magic would make it harder. Moreover, CSS and me are no friends.

Comment: you can always nest tables within tables if that helps

Comment: This means a 16 level deep hierarchy (`tr`, `td`, `table`, and implicit `tbody`). But I see that what I wanted wasn't a good idea.