# adding extra html tags within angularjs loop

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to add extra HTML tags within an angularjs loop like so:

```
 <div ng-repeat="fixture in fixtures.fixtures ">
        <tr>
          <th class="date" colspan="5">{{fixture.date | cmdate:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{{teamName(fixture.homeTeam) }}</td>
          <td>&nbsp;{{score(fixture.goalsHomeTeam)}}</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>{{score(fixture.goalsAwayTeam)}}&nbsp;</td>
          <td>{{teamName(fixture.awayTeam)}}</td>
        </tr>
  </div>
```

however no data is retrieved when I do that, if I have it coded as follows it does work:

```
   <tr ng-repeat="fixture in fixtures.fixtures ">
              <td>{{fixture.date | cmdate:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</td>
              <td>{{teamName(fixture.homeTeam) }}</td>
               <td>&nbsp;{{score(fixture.goalsHomeTeam)}}</td>
              <td>-</td>
              <td>{{score(fixture.goalsAwayTeam)}}&nbsp;</td>
              <td>{{teamName(fixture.awayTeam)}}</td>
      </tr>
```

what would be the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18097648/1911755

Comment: voodoo mode...  It's not valid to add a div tag around table rows or cells inside your table.  Instead of a div tag, why not make it a table tag (or table body)?